# getting error when trying start server in pywebio 1.5.2

Tags: python

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\website\Desktop\collector.py", line 10, in <module>
    start_server(636)
  File "C:\Users\website\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywebio\platform\tornado.py", line 360, in start_server
    handler = webio_handler(applications, cdn, allowed_origins=allowed_origins, check_origin=check_origin,
  File "C:\Users\website\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywebio\platform\tornado.py", line 236, in webio_handler
    applications = make_applications(applications)
  File "C:\Users\website\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywebio\platform\page.py", line 171, in make_applications
    assert iscoroutinefunction(app) or isgeneratorfunction(app) or callable(app), \
AssertionError: Don't support application type:<class 'int'>
```

my code:

```
from time import sleep
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio import start_server

import pandas

pandas.options.display.max_rows = 6000
pandas.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)


a = pandas.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/latest/owid-covid-latest.csv", 
    delimiter=",", 
    )


out = (a[["location",  "new_cases", "total_cases","new_deaths","total_deaths"]].to_string().replace('\n','\n'+' '*12))
out1 = '{:<11} {}'.format('',out)

Titles1 = out1.replace("location", "Location")
Titles2 = Titles1.replace("new_cases", "New Cases")
Titles3 = Titles2.replace("total_deaths", "Total Deaths")
Titles4 = Titles3.replace("total_cases", "Total Cases")
Titles5 = Titles4.replace("new_deaths", "New deaths")
No0 = Titles5.replace(".0", "")
print(No0)
put_code(No0)
start_server(636)
```

what I do wrong? Please sorry if somebody asking this question but I can't find answer in Google.
Thanks for suggestions because I'm newbie on this forum :)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should try to add some code to make this question a reproducible example for us to help you. You should read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and come back here to correct this, thanks!!

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! I publish my code and hope someone could help me! Sorry for mistakes, coz I'm newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from this line:

```
start_server(636)
```

Note that from the [documentation](https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platform.html?highlight=start_server#pywebio.platform.tornado.start_server), `start_server()`'s first argument `applications` must be a  `list` or a `dict` or a `callable`

```
pywebio.platform.tornado.start_server(applications, port=0, host='', debug=False, cdn=True, static_dir=None, remote_access=False, reconnect_timeout=0, allowed_origins=None, check_origin=None, auto_open_webbrowser=False, max_payload_size='200M', **tornado_app_settings)
```

> - applications (list/dict/callable)
>
> PyWebIO application. Can be a task function, a list of functions, or a dictionary. Refer to Advanced topic: Multiple applications in start_server() for more information.
>
> When the task function is a coroutine function, use Coroutine-based session implementation, otherwise, use thread-based session implementation.

The error is telling you that you gave an argument of an unsupported type (`int`) to the `application` argument.

> AssertionError: Don't support application type:<class 'int'>

If you meant for `636` to be the port on which your server runs, it needs to be the second argument, or passed as a keyword argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! You don't even know how you helped me!